# Date Formatting is Weird

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a date string that looks like this:

```
1391640679661
```

When I use this code:

```
NSString *seconds = @"1391640679661";
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[seconds doubleValue]];
```

I end up with this:

```
46069-05-03 07:27:41 +0000
```

So what's happening here? Is this a particular date format that I'm not accounting for? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Your value is in milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a timestamp string into NSDate, you need to divid the timestamp double value to 1000, and then call dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:

```
NSString *timestamp = @"1391640679661";
double seconds = [timestamp doubleValue]/1000.0;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
```

The result is:

2014-02-05 22:51:19 +0000

Answer (score 2):

Apple's own api will do all the hard work for you to format components as per your need.

If you want to get individual components as well you can apply below approach.

```
NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = 1391640679661;

// Get the system calendar
 NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1]; 

// Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

NSLog(@"Conversion: %dmin %dhours %ddays %dmoths",[conversionInfo minute], [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo day], [conversionInfo month]);
```